# how can I plot several signals on the same figure with the same axis in python

Tags: python

I represented 22 signals in the same figure manually

```
plt.plot(components + [0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 1.55])
plt.yticks([0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 1.55], ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21'])
plt.xlim([0, 15000])
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVXSj.png)

but when I tried to do it automatically. I did not succeed.

```
for i in range(0, 21):
    plt.plot(components[:, i])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRkKh.png)

Is there anyone who can help me please

Comment: `+ [0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.35, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 1.55])` has been omitted in your second example, that's what separated all the graphs.  They will not separate if you don't add this. You can name this in a list and pull the `i`th element from it in each pass of your for loop

Comment: Does `plt.plot(components[:, i] + i)` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the example here https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html?highlight=multiple%20plots#multiple-y-axis-scales

The source code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('sin')
plt.show()
```

You can see they use a separate `ax2` but the end result is to put it on one graph. You can choose to keep the same x-scale, or the same y-scale between plots via `.twinx()` or `.twiny()`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and your help. For those who have encountered the same problem and who are eager to solve it, this link will help you: [link](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/specialty_plots/mri_with_eeg.html)